# Updating some rows dynamically in TableLayout

Tags: android, dynamic, rows, tablelayout

I'm adding rows to my `TableLayout` dynamically and each row has more than one `TextView`.

I want to loop for each row in my `TableLayout` and I want to update some rows (not every row), for example the text of `TextView` in my rows. How can I manage this?

Comment: post the code which you have attempted if any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loop through the children of the TableLayout, they should be TableRows (or another layout) - skip the ones you don't want to update. Loop through or findViewById the children of the TableRow (or whatever) which will be your TextViews

When you add the TextView / CheckBox to the TableRow, you can set the View's id with setId(R.id.id_of_the_view) (which you might want to add to the res/values/ids.xml file).

Then loop through like so:

```
TableLayout tableLayout = null;
for(int n = 0, s = tableLayout.getChildCount(); n < s; ++n) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow)tableLayout.getChildAt(n);
    TextView name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
}
```

since you're using row.findViewById, you're looking for a specific id inside a specific row.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply. But I don't know how can I loop through the children(my children are TableRows) of TableLayout. Then, another problem is I'm adding TableRows and TextViews, CheckBoxes for each TableRow dynamically. How can I reach the id of specific TextView in a specific TableRow? I'm asking so that you told about "findViewById".

Comment: Thank you, I will try it but as far as I seen it's very logical.

Comment: I also want to learn how can I loop in ListView like this way?

And I want to assign checkbox id from code, like checkbox1, checkbox2, then also, I want to control from 1 to 100 for example if they are checked. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm using your code, but there is a problem : tableLayout.getChildCount() returns the multiplication of the number of rows and 2. For example, I have 5 rows and each row has 2 TextViews and 1 CheckBoxes. I could not understand why getChildCount() returns 10. When I get the first child from tableLayout like `TableRow row = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(0)`
it's working, however getChildAt(1) returns a silly row whose id is -1. For all odd numbers, the id of component returns -1.

Comment: The -1 id'ed rows might be the dividers between the rows?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the setTag method to quick reach specific rows, and Views within rows.

For example, lets say you have a CheckBox in a certain column, which represents "isSomethingEnabled". When creating the CheckBox, do setTag("foo").

Use setTag on the row as well, such as setTag("rowKey")

To quickly get to a specific row

TableRow tRow = (TableRow) tLayout.findViewWithTag("rowKey");

And to quickly get to a specific child

View v = tRow.findViewWithTag("foo");